# How to import remark-gfm in next.config.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, mdxjs, remarkjs

I want to use MDX in next.js and remark-gfm plugin. I found [Next.js Docs about MDX](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/using-mdx#setup-nextmdx-in-nextjs) and follow this. and add import statement.

```
// next.config.js
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm;'

const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: []
  }
})

module.exports = withTM(
  withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  })
)
```

I executed `npm run dev`, and error occurs.
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I tried changing `import` to `require`, but another error occurs.

`Error [ERR_ERQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/me/myblog/node_modules/remark-gfm/index.js from /home/me/myblog/next.config.js not supported.`

How can i import remark-gfm? Is it impossible?

Comment: I cannot resolve this error. To convert mdx to JSX with plugins, I used `compile` function at @mdx-js/mdx. `compile` return JSX builder function in string format and I have to convert it to Function and Call this function like this `const JSXObject = Function(compiled)(React)` it's complicated and not elegant way.

Comment: I am reasonably certain I've seen answers to this question here on StackOverflow. Have you searched? As I recall, one solution relates to needing a `package.json` file with something like `type="module"`.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work by changing the file name of `next.config.js` to `next.config.mjs` to support ES Modules.

**File:** `next.config.mjs`

```
import nextMdx from '@next/mdx';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm;'

const withMDX = nextMdx({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
    rehypePlugins: []
  }
});

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
};

export default withMDX(nextConfig);
```